# Hooking into Windows File Copy

Tags: winapi, api, hook

I want to write my own file copy program that will run when the user chooses '**Paste**' / (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) in Windows Explorer. Some programs like **CopyHandler** and **SuperCopier** are doing this. But I don't know how.

Please help.

Comment: always post questions with some efforts put

Answer (score 2):

The project [catchcopy](http://catchcopy.first-world.info/) used by [Ultracopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/) and [Supercopier](http://ultracopier.first-world.info/supercopier.html), provide all abstraction of that's. You just need listen named pipe to receive the copy/move to do from the explorer. All is detailed into the wiki.

Comment: Just noting: my IT department came by because their firewall flagged Ultracopier as malware. I explained to him about the project, but he believes there is a legitimate concern with the software.

Comment: From reading online, the free version of Ultracopier may come with mining software to use your computer to make money.

Comment: This is incorrect, the current version don't have any mining software. More than 1 year ago had one version (the cracked) with mining (to try fight the illegal version of the cracked software, the normal version and paid version was never shipped with it), but not now. This was be validated with the community.

Comment: Ultracopier is actually used into the French government, then verified by IT expert. And here we spoke about catchcopy, then lib as Qt used into Ultracopier. Not Ultracopier.